# Python: Pandas Pivot DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

For the  below DataFrame:

| ID | Reg | Departure | Arrival | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | DUB | LCY | 22/0/22 | 15:23 |
| 2 | ABC | DUB | LCY | 22/0/22 | 15:27 |
| 3 | CBA | CPH | HEL | 22/0/22 | 12:21 |
| 4 | CBA | CPH | HE | 22/0/22 | 12:19 |

I would like to pivot so that it so that the resulting DataFrame is:

| ID | Reg | Departure | Arrival | Date | Time | ID2 | Time2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | DUB | LCY | 22/0/22 | 15:23 | 2 | 15:27 |
| 3 | CBA | CPH | HEL | 22/0/22 | 12:21 | 4 | 12:19 |

I've been playing around with GroupBy & Pivot but haven't managed to crack it, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please go into more detail about the assumptions we can make. What if for the same Reg the Departure would differ? Or the Arrival? What's fixed for combinations of certain columns and what's not?

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned. The assumption is that Reg, Departure, Arrival & Date should have one duplicate row, so i'm trying to merge those two, and keep the ID & Time cols (as they won't be duplicates) as new columns. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

So this will work if you have just two of each Reg row. But if you have more duplicate rows you will need something more robust.

import data and pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

output

```
    ID  Reg Departure   Arrival Date    Time
0   1   ABC DUB         LCY     22/0/22 15:23
1   2   ABC DUB         LCY     22/0/22 15:27
2   3   CBA CPH         HEL     22/0/22 12:21
3   4   CBA CPH         HE      22/0/22 12:19
```

make two frames with with 'firsts' and one with 'lasts'

```
final_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', subset='Departure')
id_time_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='last', subset='Departure')
```

Then merge the two frames

```
pd.merge(final_df, id_time_df[['ID', 'Reg', 'Time']], on='Reg')
```

output

```
    ID_x    Reg Departure   Arrival Date    Time_x  ID_y    Time_y
0   1       ABC DUB         LCY     22/0/22 15:23   2       15:27
1   3       CBA CPH         HEL     22/0/22 12:21   4       12:19
```

Answer (score 1):

**Initialize the dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd
import io
str = '''ID Reg Departure   Arrival Date    Time
1   ABC DUB LCY 22/0/22 15:23
2   ABC DUB LCY 22/0/22 15:27
3   CBA CPH HEL 22/0/22 12:21
4   CBA CPH HEL 22/0/22 12:19'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str), sep = '\s+')
```

We first create a sequence number by group for `unstack()` later .

```
df["grpseq"] = df.groupby(["Reg", "Departure", "Arrival", "Date"]).cumcount()

df_new = df.set_index(["Reg", "Departure", "Arrival", "Date", "grpseq"]).unstack(level = -1).reset_index()
df_new.columns = ["Reg", "Departure", "Arrival", "Date", "ID1", "ID2", "Time1", "Time2"]

df_new
    Reg  Departure  Arrival    Date    ID1  ID2 Time1   Time2
0   ABC      DUB       LCY     22/0/22  1   2   15:23   15:27
1   CBA      CPH       HEL     22/0/22  3   4   12:21   12:19
```

Where `ID1` represent the `ID` column in your desire table. And a simple reorder of the columns will be done.